# Retrieve Assortments (Dutch: "Assortimenten") on Exact Online

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

For a CSV dump of articles with stock and price information from Exact Online, I need to restrict the list of articles the CSV to articles in an Assortment (Dutch: "Assortiment").

The REST-APIs do not seem to offer this information. It is possible to retrieve Item information, but the assortment is nowhere to be found:

```
select * from exactonlinerest..items
```

It seems weird that it is missing from the APIs. Assortments are used often on Exact Online.

An alternative might be to maintain a separate table in addition to Exact Online for assortimenten (assortments).

Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [XML API](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/invantive-eol-provider-exactonlinexml-xml-itemcategories.html) better:

```
select * from itemcategories
```

But note that the fields have a totally different naming style, since the XML APIs have typically very long column names. For item code, it would be `ITEM_CODE_ATTR`.

The GUIDs are only present in some weird text format `{GUID}`, so remember to remove the `{` and `}` first.